# Is there a way to increase density of data of scatter data?

Tags: matlab

I have this x y data:

[image]

I would like to increase the density of points by closing small gaps. How do i go about. I still want to preserve the structure of the points.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by 'closing gaps'.
if you mean that you want to make the data **seem** more grouped without actually adding more data points, then you might find the 'LineWidth' argument to be useful. If used currectly it increases the width of each marker in the scatter plot, which will make the data seem more grouped and with less gaps.
to use it, write the scatter code line as follows:

```
scatter(X, Y, 'LneWidth', width_number)
```

replace 'width_number' with different values and see the effect.